# Tableau and its first prolongation for linear Pfaffian systems

Tags: differential-equations, exterior-algebra

This question concerns characterization of tableau associated with an exterior differential system (EDS).

On the one hand, we have prop 4.2 in the EDS book by Bryant et al.:

Given an EDS on a manifold M, if the integral elements over a fixed point m in M form a smooth manifold then the tableau at such an integral element E is the tangent space to integral elements over m at E.

On the other hand, in a later discussion of linear Pfaffian systems (a particular sort of EDS) in the same chapter, we find prop. 5.7, which says the following:

Given a linear Pfaffian system over a manifold M and a fixed point m in M over which the set of integral elements is non-empty, the integral elements over m comprise an affine space whose associated vector space is the first prolongation of the tableau at m.

Since the tangent space to an affine space is the same thing as its associated vector space, and since the first prolongation of a tableau is not the same as the tableau itself, these two propositions appear to be at odds.

My question: Are there two separate notions of tableau associated with an EDS being used in these two propositions, or are they actually contradictory? I suspect the former because the authors go out of their way to call the Cartan characters associated with tableau for linear Pfaffian systems “reduced” characters on p. 133. But I’m also confused as to why there is not more discussion of the distinction between these two notions, if it exists.